# $http PUT request is slow and unsuccessful no status code, no errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When a user submits a form, the server should receive a PUT request that updates the poll database. What's odd is that in my dev console, I can see that the callback for Poll.update is called immediately, but the PUT request takes 120000 ms. And then even though the dev console shows a successful PUT request, the database isn't updated, and my .success callback is never called.

> Updated [object Object]
>
> PUT /api/polls/5599725069753a7711fd4274/0 200 120083ms

In my browser I only see a PUT request without a status code. I don't see any error messages.

The routes for the Poll controller:

```
 var express = require('express');
 var controller = require('./poll.controller');
 var router = express.Router();

 router.put('/:id', controller.update);

 module.exports = router;
```

The Mongoose Poll controller:

```
exports.update = function(req, res) { 
  var update = {$set: {'poll_name': 'Poll has been updated'}};

  Poll.update(req.params.id, update, function(err, num, doc) {
  if(err) console.log(err);
  else {
    console.log('Updated ' + doc); // This is logged after vote is submitted
    }
});
};
```

Angular code that's called when submit is clicked:

```
$scope.addVote = function() {
  $http.put('api/polls/' + $scope._id).success(function(result) {
      console.log('Vote submitted'); //This is never called
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: could you add error function in the call so that you would no the reason behind error by debugging it `.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log('Vote submitted'); //This is never called
    }
  )`

Comment: If you do not call "res.end" or better "res.json" the call will not close ever, in fact enters the timeout set by express for calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server isn't sending any response and that's the reason why you see the request ending after a long time. Add a res.send after your console.log and you will see the response received on the client side

Comment: Yes. At least send a res.status(200) or res.status(201) back to the client. Otherwise, your request is timing out.